# Definite Integral of exponential function with changed limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function

I want to integrate in terms of x:

[image]

I know the integral of:

[image]

but can't seem to figure out the first integral.

Comment: Completes the square. It must be related to $\texttt{erfc}$ function.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-ax^2-bx} = \mathrm{e}^{-a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)} 
$$
So we have an integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)} dx = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2} dx 
$$
using $z^2 = a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 \to dz = \sqrt{a} dx$
so we have 
$$
 \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{\frac{b}{\sqrt{4a}}}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-z^2}dx 
$$
using 
$$
1-\mathrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-z^2}dx 
$$
so we get
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^2-bx} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\left(1-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{4a}}\right)\right)
$$